# Magnific popup - undefined is not a function when parsing markup

Tags: magnific-popup

So I'm using Magnific Popup and whenever I use my own inline template and do the whole parsing of the markup, the line that fails is 231. Here is my code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbaWLa

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="featured-works" class="gallery">
    <div class="piece">
        <a rel="gallery" title="Girl Holding Flowers" href="/themes/images/grid/image1.png" data-description="This one has a description">
            <p class="caption">Girl Holding Flowers</p>
            <img src="/themes/images/grid/image1.png" alt="image" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="piece">
        <a rel="gallery" title="Girl Kissing Father" href="/themes/images/grid/image2.png" data-description="">
            <p class="caption">Girl Kissing Father</p>
            <img src="/themes/images/grid/image2.png" alt="image" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var data = [];

$('.gallery a').each(function(e) {

    var item = {
        title: $(this).attr('title'),
        href_img: $(this).attr('href'),
        description: $(this).attr('data-description')
    };

    data.push( item );

});

$(".gallery").magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    items: data,
    type: 'inline',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    inline: {
        // Define markup. CLass names should match key names.
        markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
        '<span class="mfp-title"></span>' +
        '<div class="mfp-href"></div>' +
        '<div class="mfp-description"></div>' +
        '</div>'
    },
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

The line that is failing is 231 in magnific popup which is in the _parseMarkup function. This is how that function looks:

```
_parseMarkup: function(b, c, d) {
    var e;
    d.data && (c = a.extend(d.data, c)), y(f, [b, c, d]), a.each(c, function(a, c) {
        if (c === undefined || c === !1) return !0;
        e = a.split("_");
        if (e.length > 1) {
            var d = b.find(j + "-" + e[0]);
            if (d.length > 0) {
                var f = e[1];
                f === "replaceWith" ? d[0] !== c[0] && d.replaceWith(c) : f === "img" ? d.is("img") ? d.attr("src", c) : d.replaceWith('<img src="' + c + '" class="' + d.attr("class") + '" />') : d.attr(e[1], c)
            }
        } else b.find(j + "-" + a).html(c)
    })
},
```

The code: `e = a.split("_");` is what is failing.. it's saying undefined is not a function. I did a console.log(a) before that and before the error is thrown, 0 is returned.. I don't know where they got that 0 from though so.. not sure.

When I do a console.log() on my data variable, this is what is being pulled:

```
Object, Object]0: Object
  description: ""
  href_img: "http://rayndee.localhost/themes/light-fixed-width/images/grid/image2.png"
  title: "Girl Kissing Father"
  __proto__: Object
1: Object
  description: "This one has a description"
  href_img: "http://rayndee.localhost/themes/light-fixed-width/images/grid/image1.png"
  title: "Girl Holding Flowers"
  __proto__: Object
length: 2__proto__: Array[0]
```

Thank you for any help!